# Where have all the sandpipers gone?

Tags: birds, sea, california, migration

(long time passing).

I walk along Del Monte beach in Crow City, USA (Monterey, California) quite often.

For quite awhile, sandpipers were there in abundance - more than any other bird.

I haven't seen any in a couple of months.

Have they migrated away? Where?

According to [this](http://www.seagrant.wisc.edu/birds/spotted_sandpiper_migration.html), sandpipers are "year-round" residents in my area (well, "spotted" sandpipers, anyway, I don't know what subspecies these are that are common to my area).

Comment: Is there some construction going on in the area?

Comment: No, none is allowed nearby.

Comment: Updated - Del Monte beach, just north of Fisherman's Wharf.

Comment: They are back now (11/24/16); it has been a couple of weeks since I've been to the beach, so sometime around mid-November, I reckon, they returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost all North American sandpipers nest far up north (from the northern Great Plains to the shores of the Arctic Ocean). They winter in moderate numbers along the coasts, and very large numbers of migrants come through in waves along the coasts in the spring (March-May, mostly). The numbers in southbound migration (August-October, mostly) are somewhat lower on the coast, because much of the southbound migration takes place inland. In most of the lower 48 U.S. states, June & July are almost completely without sandpipers. There are detailed discussions of migration (and much more useful information) in [O'Brien and Crossley, The Shorebird Guide](http://www.10000birds.com/theshorebirdguide.htm).